# Multivariable Calculus Vector Field Potential

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

How could I tell if the following vector field $$\vec{f}(x,y,z)=(xy+1)(e^xy e^yz e^z) \mathbf{i} \ + \ (x^2+xz)(e^xy e^yz e^z) \mathbf{j} \ + \ (xy+x)(e^xy e^yz e^z) \mathbf{k}$$ has potential without actually calculating the potential? Any explained solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This probably has to do with closed and exact 1-forms (although you may have different names in your course).

Answer (score 1):

Existence of potential of vector field depends on both vector field and topology. The same vector field can turn from potential field to non-potential field if I dig a hole somewhere.

Assuming the vector field above is well-defined on $\mathbb R^3$, then according to [Poincare's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincare_lemma), it's sufficient to verify that the total differential $df=0$. Or if we can write the vector field $V=(P,Q,R)$, we need to show
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial R}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial R}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial z}=0$$

Comment: Depending on what point you've reached in vector analysis, this is the same as checking as to whether the "curl" of $ \ \vec{f} \ , \ \nabla \times \vec{f} \ , $ is zero.  Such a vector field is variously called "conservative", "curl-free", or "irrotational" in different disciplines.  A potential function can be found for such a vector field.

Comment: The second sentence seems wrong to me.